# Check and save emails from GMAIL as PDF from command line?

Tags: shell, pdf, curl, gmail

I'd like to build a script that can basically log into GMail, check for certain mail by a given criteria, save the conversation as a PDF (or something) on my local machine, and then log off. Has anyone done something like this before?

Answer (score 0):

Accessing gmail service depend on the protocol you choose, namely pop or imap.
Find here a script to open a session and access your mailbox:
http://glaudiston.blogspot.fr/2011/08/gmail-acess-via-bash-imap.html

Note also that your gmail account publishes its mail as an RSS feed. To see the last unread email (though it is not what you want to do).

```
curl -u LOGIN:PASSWORD --silent "https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom"| perl -ne 'print "\t" if /<name>/; print "$2\n" if /<(title|name)>(.*)<\/\1>/;'
```

Once you have downloaded your email, its is quite simple to export them into pdf:
you should find many packages to do that in linux (search for pdf in your package manager). You may also start with a2ps.